# C casting unsigned char to unsigned char : 4

Tags: c

I currently have an issue concerning a warning. I have a method return a `u8` value, where `u8` was defined as `unsigned char`.

```
u8 foo (...)
```

And inside a structure I have a member `x` that only needs 4 bits.

```
struct {
     u8 x : 4;
     u8 y : 4;
} s;
```

Now I want to assign the return value of `foo` to `x`. However my compiler throws a warning about possible loss by conversion from `unsigned char` to `unsigned char : 4`. Yet a cast like this isn't recognized.

```
struct_inst.x = (u8 : 4)foo(..);
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: You cannot express bit-width in type-casting like that.Try AND'ing with a bitmask instead: `struct_inst.x = foo(..) & 0x0F;`. BTW which compiler are you using?

Comment: The warning is correct. Unless the compiler knows that the value returned by `foo()` is in the range 0..15, the implicit conversion could lose information. As @MortenJensen suggests, a bit mask discards the upper bits explicitly.

Comment: The warning wont dissappear. I modified the code like this
[code]
walker->height.current = map_get_tile_level(from_x, from_y) & 0xF
[/code]
And i am using devkit pro's gcc

Comment: @WodkaRHR Which version of GCC is that? I can't reproduce with GCC 4.7.4-2 on Debian. From google searches I see that older versions had the bug. If you can get a newer version of GCC, maybe you can get rid of the bug :)? I think mainline is beyond 5.3 at this moment.

Comment: Note: don't use hoimebrew fixed-width types. They are obsolete since ca. 17 years. The C standard provides `stdint.h` with `uint8_t` and other useful types (some are only available if the target supports them).

Answer (score 4):

Bitfield types as you have them with your `:4` aren't proper types in C's type system, so you cannot use them in casts.

Your compiler warning is a bit execessive, conversion from one unsigned type to another is well defined. The sense of the warning is correct, nevertheless, converting an 8 bit type to a 4 bit field may loose information. Maybe you could silence your compiler by anding your return value with `0xF` so the compiler sees that you are willingly throwing the higher bits away.

BTW:

- There is a type `uint8_t` in `<stdint.h>` that has the properties that you want.
- Using types that are narrower than `int` is not a good idea in most cases, because they always promote to `int` in arithmetic, anyhow. Only use them if the few bytes that you gain are really worth it. They aren't if you have Gigabytes of memory in your system, e.g.
- Bitfields are even less usefull than narrow integer types.

Comment: & 0xF will not fix the issue since the warning does not dissappear.

Comment: @WodkaRHR, too bad. Then review your compiler warnings and switch off warning for unsigned to unsigned conversion. Or even better just avoid using narrow types.

Comment: +1 Jens Gustedt: I've stopped using bitfields exactly because of this, and also because GCC oftens generated more bloated code, than if you handle the packing yourself. I've just begun doing that instead...

Comment: problem is that i am reverse engineering a game and the predefined structures are desinged in this way... well than it can not be helped thank you all nevertheless

Comment: Using gcc 7.3:
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)

The trick with & 0x0F works well.

For the MSB use 0xF0
for the LSB use 0x0F